# Find the derivative of $f(x) = e^{1\over x^2}$ using the definition

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have the formula $f(x) = e^{1\over x^2}$
if $x ≠ 0$ and $f(0) = 0$.

I have to:

1.

use the deﬁnition of derivative to compute $f'(0)$ and

2.

find out whether $f'(x)$ is diﬀerentiable at $x=0$

For the first part I already have $lim h->0 = {e^{-1\over h^2}\over h}$ 
But I don't know how to continue

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you know about the exponential function?

Comment: I'd appreciate all the help :)

Comment: Well I know that it is not defined for x=0, but what do you mean?

Comment: I didn't mean $x\mapsto e^{-1/x^2}$, but rather $x\mapsto e^x$. How was the exponential function ($x\mapsto e^x$) defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $\frac{1}{x^2}=t$ or

$|x|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ or

$\frac{1}{|x|}=\sqrt{t}$.

when $x$ goes to $0$, $t$ tends to
$+\infty$.

let us compute

$f'(0^+)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-0}{x-0}=\lim_{t\to +\infty}\sqrt{t}e^{-t}$

we know that near $+\infty$, the exponential is faster than the power.

so, $\lim_{t\to +\infty}\sqrt{t}e^{-t}=0$

we have the same result for $f'(0^-)=\lim_{t\to +\infty}-\sqrt{t}e^{-t}$.

the derivative of $f$ at $x=0$ is zero.

Comment: I'm sorry but where does the root in the limit come from?

Comment: please, read the answer from the first line.

Comment: @Susan is it ok?

Comment: Yes, I get what you do and appreciate all the steps, but (maybe a stupid question) where do you use the definition of a derivative?

Comment: in the $6^th$ line from above.

Comment: Oh haha I see it now, thanks a lot!